# Price based on Quanity

Tags: magento-1.9, admin

We are a distributor and we have two price rules, 
Standard
Bulk
so if you buy 1-4 or 1-9 you get standard trade price, however if you buy 5 or more or 10 or more then you get bulk

But i can't find how do it on drop down.
So with our products they have flavours. so if there are 10 flavours, they can buy 1 of each one, as long as there is 10 more they will get the discount.

Please can someone advice on this as its core to our business.

Answer (score 0):

This extension has the abilities you are looking for, I think. It's also affordable. I have only used it a few times, but I have had no issues.

[Tiered Pricing Across Multiple Products](http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/tiered-pricing-across-multiple-products.html?utm_campaign=bazaarvoice&utm_medium=SearchVoice&utm_source=AskAndAnswer&utm_content=Default)

Comment: Thanks, Just watched the video and this looks like it, thanks alot

Comment: No worries. If you can mark my answer as accepted future users will be able to find this solution. Good luck!